# How to implement Multipane Fragment with same UI but different views for Tablet and Device in andorid?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to implement a Multiplane Fragment for Tablet and Same UI should be used as a ListView and on list item click new fragment with its details in Mobile Device in Android. The below Image will illustrate more what I need.

[image]

I have reffered the below mentioned links and Tutorials, But non has explained how to do this.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

[Nested Fragments (multi-pane in tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981286/nested-fragments-multi-pane-in-tab)

Can anyone help me how to do so?

Comment: **Android Studio** > **File** > **New Project** > create a new project with **Master / Detail Flow** is not good for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement two different fragments. One for phone, one for tablet and then add two xml files one in **layout** folder which will contain first fragment (for phone) and seconds with same name but in **layout-w800** folder which will contain second fragment (for tablet). Then in activity you need just setContentView with your layout and that's all.

But I would suggest to you more elegant way described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html)